# How to Improve RecyclerView Adapter and Is It Good Practice? I was wondering how this could be improved

Tags: android, adapter

How to Improve RecyclerView Adapter and Is It Good Practice?

I've implemented a RecyclerView adapter to display a list of news articles. I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve this code and whether it adheres to best practices in Android development. Here's the adapter code:

```
class NewsAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {

    private object NewsDiffUtil : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, NewsDiffUtil)

    inner class ArticleViewHolder(val binding: ItemArticleBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        return ArticleViewHolder(
            ItemArticleBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
            )
        )
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val article = differ.currentList[position]
        Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(article.urlToImage).into(holder.binding.ivArticleImage)
        holder.binding.tvSource.text = article.title
        holder.binding.tvTitle.text = article.title
        holder.binding.tvDescription.text = article.description
        holder.binding.tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickListener?.let {
                it(article)
            }
        }
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((Article) -> Unit)? = null
    fun setOnClickListener(listener: (Article) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO. my only advice would be that you could have used `holder.binding.apply { }` and then put a lot of your assignments in there, it makes no difference to actual functionality though

Answer (score 0):

- Use ListAdapter
- Use requestmanager from Glid and pass it to the adapter.
- don't set the click listener onbind, rather set it once on the viewholder and use a callback.